# Locals Window does not show anything; only happens on specific method in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have a specific project that I'm working on - a plugin for another application - and I am unable to track variable values within a specific method.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. I've littered the project with breakpoints trying to get some sort of direction as to how to track these variables, and I've had no luck whatsoever.

```
[Plugin]
public class MIRequestPlugin
{
    public static QuoteRequestClient client;
    public MIRequestPlugin()
    {
        if (EncompassApplication.CurrentUser.ID == /*My username*/)
        {
            EncompassApplication.LoanOpened += new EventHandler(AttachToFieldChange);
        }
    }

    private void MIPull(object sender, FieldChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.FieldID == "CX.MIREQUEST.TRIGGER" && e.NewValue == "Y")
        {
            gatherRateInfo();
        }
    }

    private void AttachToFieldChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EncompassApplication.CurrentLoan.FieldChange += new FieldChangeEventHandler(MIPull);
    }

    private void gatherRateInfo()
    {
        List<string> borrEntFirst = new List<string>();
        List<string> borrEntLast = new List<string>();
        string isPud = "";

        if (Convert.ToString(EncompassApplication.CurrentLoan.Fields["4006"].Value) != "" && EncompassApplication.CurrentLoan.Fields["4006"].Value != null)
        {
            borrEntFirst = new List<string> { "4000", "4004" };
            borrEntLast = new List<string> { "4002", "4006" }; 
        }

[...]
```

The rest of the code really isn't important. Within the gatherRateInfo method, I need to be able to track the values held in borrEntFirst and borrEntLast. When the debugger hits the breakpoint at

> string isPud = "";

Nothing is displayed in the Locals window. Furthermore, I can't use mouse-over on any of the entities in the code either. I've placed breakpoints on half a dozen lines further into the method, and still no Locals. To *further* complicate my situation, I can see Locals and get mouse-over info if I break at the constructor.

I'm attaching to the only process with the same name as the application where the plugin lives, and Symbols are loading just fine.

I've tried high-level fixes such as repairing my VS, and I even go so desperate as to reinstall VS2015. I've changed my symbol servers to http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols. I've created a new solution and added the existing project. I've checked for Managed Compatibility (which doesn't appear to exist in VS2015). I've tried just about everything that's been suggest for other instances of this issue here on SE and Microsoft's website. What else can I try to get to a point where I can track my locals in this method while debugging this project?

EDIT: I was able to manually add watches to the variables in question. As it turns out, for the two List variables, I'm given the following error:

> error CS0012: The type 'RestClient' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'RestSharp, Version=105.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

This is confusing for two reasons. One is that I do indeed have a reference to the RestSharp Version 105.2.3.0 assembly in my project. The second is that the creation of a List variable should have nothing to do with the RestSharp assembly. Furthermore, the project compiles without issue. Really stuck here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the locals window show values for other project types (for example a console app), or  is it just an issue with your project type?

Comment: Not only does it show values for other project types, it will show the Locals in other methods of the same project. It's just for the method that I'm debugging that it won't show them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days and days of trying to solve this issue, the answer was quite a bit simpler than I was making it. The software into which my code is plugging - Encompass - needed the RestSharp dll to be loaded in as its own plugin.

Just in case anyone else is running into a similar issue creating plugins for Encompass, this is how you solve this issue.